# Parsing or Reading password protected pdf files

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to parse pdf files using c#, but it can be password protected file also. Then 
is there any way to parse it ?

After parsing it I want to convert that text into html format.And I want to parse
more than one pdf file at a time. And from that pdf files some can be password
protected and some can be without password.

So is there any way to parse or read that pdf file which is password protected ?

Is there any parser to parse password protected pdf files.

**EDIT:** I do not have any password to open the pdf files and password to open the password protected pdf files will be different for each pdf file. Because user who will use this functionality have password for opening pdf file. But I want to give the facility to the user to import the text from the pdf files and want to fill that texts in datagridview.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)? Documentation is thin on the ground, but in the Java version at least you can specify the password when you read a document.

EDIT: All of this is assuming that at the time you want to read the document, you have the password - e.g. supplied by the user. You won't be able to access the contents of the document without the password, as that would render password protection irrelevant.

Your edit is unclear, as you say you *don't* have any password, but then that the user does... surely that means you *do* have the password, because you can ask the user.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I wanted to say that I have sample pdf files of the user but do not have password for it, but user will have password of that pdf files. I want to make the functionality that when just user click on one button and pdf files will be parsed and datagridview will be filled by that parsed text, and user will not have to apply the password.

Comment: @Harikrishna: Well you won't need the password to be hardcoded or anything - you'll just ask the user for the password at the same time that you ask them for the PDF itself. The user *will* have to specify the password. There's simply no way round that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, That is ok, but if user wants to parse more than one pdf file at a time by selecting all the pdf files and password for the pdf file can be different then how it is possible to ask for the password multiple times ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: You could ask for them as you parse them, or pop up a dialog with a list of files and a space for them to enter the password for each one. All of this is completely outside the scope of the original question though... how you *get* the password is entirely separate from how you parse a PDF given the file and the password.

Comment: @Jon Skeet,Then it is impossible to make generic unlock mechanism to parse password protected files, is it ? And yes then can I detect that pdf file is password protected or not ?

Comment: @Harikrishna: Yes, it's impossible to make a generic unlock mechanism which doesn't require the password. Is that surprising? I don't know how simple it is to detect that it's password protected - but I would imagine it's not terribly hard.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  I would hope not.

I would expect the file to be encrypted using data from the actual password, so there should be no generic unlock mechanism available.

Comment: Are you assuming the OP doesn't *have* the password?

Comment: Ah yes...that is how I read it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet,That is the thing,I will not have any password to open it, and password to open pdf files will be different.

Comment: @Harikrishna: Oh - in that case I'm surprised you even asked. What would be the point of password-protecting something if someone without the password could open it? See the edit to my answer - it's not really clear whether you have or haven't got the password when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to check if a PDF file is encrypted and for opening encrypted files.

You can use one of the [GetEncryptionInfo](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/api/pdfdocument-getencryptioninfo) methods of the library to check if a file is encrypted. If it is, then you will be able to show dialog to a user and then open PDF with provided password.

Please take a look at the sample that shows how to [check if PDF document is password protected](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/General%20operations/CheckIfPasswordProtected).

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle, vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure all that would be possible, though it's a lot of work. You will probably need to use a PDF component such as [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx)